# Codeigniter Session refreshs in every request

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter application, when the same is deployed to the server, the session cookie "ci_sesssion" value changes in every request

In framework code (file system/libraries/Session/Session.php) there is the following part:

// Sanitize the cookie, because apparently PHP doesn't do that for userspace handlers

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
    && (
        ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
        OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
    )
)
{
    unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);
}
```

It removes the cookie if it does not match the format. It is expected that the length of the cookie will be 40 characters. Before the session.hash_function and session.hash_bits_per_character parameters were responsible for the length of the cookie string, but they were deleted in PHP 7.1.

In regular expression I changed :

`preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])`

to

`preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{26}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])`.

But still the same. 
**What will be the best solution for the issue?**
Server version change is not possible, I need to fix this in the application.

Comment: i use codeigniter 3.10 on php version 7.2 with no issues regarding the session. i would suggest looking in to possibilities that do not include framework error, not only because of my own experience, but also from the fact that plenty of people use ci with the newest versions of php without session issue (no official bug report). perhaps you are using outdated version?

Comment: Are you saying that your cookie is being unset? if that is the case - have you looked at what $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name'] is prior to the code above and actually see what it is. Obviously changing the preg_match character count isn't working OR its not a string. Which one is it?

Comment: What is the exact version of CodeIgniter you are using?  PHP version?

Comment: We need also should change a-f to a-z:


preg_match('/^[0-9a-z]{26}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])

Comment: I had the same issue on a legacy codebase that is being ported to PHP7.4 (from pre 7). The solution is to update CI to the latest version. It includes a fix for this. https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L320